# Layers with same coordinate system should align/overlap in ArcMap but do not?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, layers

I put 4 different layers into my ArcMap document, but only one of them will show up on the map! I should be seeing the other 3 layers as well. When I do a *Zoom to layer*, I can see one layer, but I cannot figure out how to make the other 3 show up at once on top of each other.

Before I opened ArcMap, I used ArcCatalog where I right-clicked 3/4 of the shapefiles and  clicked *Properties* → *Coordinate system* → *Import* and then clicked on my Trees layer, which has the coordinate system I want the other 3 to have. But when I opened ArcMap the 4 layers did *not* overlap, nor could I move them above or below each other.

Answer (score 102):

**You are confusing two different operations dealing with [Projections](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003r00000001000000.htm).**

1. [Define a projection](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000077000000):  You would use this when you have a shapefile or other feature class that does not currently have a spatial reference defined when you look at the properties in ArcGIS.  You might also use this if you knew based on some observation, that the projection defined for the layer was wrong.  This could be due to recognizing that the coordinates of the features were not appropriate for the currently defined projection, or some other clue.  This operation simply overwrites the existing projection with a different one that you specify. This can also be done in ArcCatalog by changing the coordinate system in the "XY Coordinate System" tab of the feature class Properties.
2. [Project a featureclass](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Project/00170000007m000000/):  This tool is used when you have a featureclass with a defined projection, and you want to convert it to a different projection.  This will run the appropriate transformation to change the features to the coordinate space of the new projection.

In your question, you state that you have a shapefile that is currently in a `Geographic coordinate system` or `Latitude/Longtude` which has units of `Decimal Degrees`.  This means that you have coordinates in the range of `Y/Lat = 0 to 90` and `X/Lon = -180 - +180`.  When you bring this shapefile into ArcMap untouched, its projection will be recognized.  If you use the measure tool set to miles, ArcMap will calculate the distance correctly.

You then used the **Define projection** tool, which doesn't convert the coordinates, but simply changes the projection assigned to the shapefile from `Geographic` to `State Plane NAD 83 California Zone 6 Feet`.  This gives you a shapefile with units in feet.  The features in the shapefile did not have their internal coordinates converted, however, so they are still in the range of `X = -180 to +180 and Y = 0 to 90`.  Running the **Project** tool using the same coordinate system doesn't actually accomplish anything because you have already set your shapefile to this projection with the Define tool.  This is why when you use the **Measure** tool, the distance is dramatically smaller.  Essentially, your all the features of your shapefile are now fitting in a distance of 360 feet horizontally and 90 feet vertically.

**The proper procedure,** to be performed on the original shapefile in the geographic coordinate system, is to use the **Project Tool**.  For the `Projection`, choose `State Plane, NAD 1983 California Zone 6 Feet`.  The output should be in the proper location and give a correct distance when measured.  It should also overlay correctly on any other layers, provided they have a projection defined and that your Data Frame in ArcMap has a projection defined.

Answer (score 34):

Although you have set the projection of your 3 other layers by the properties menu in ArcCatalog, you have failed to re-project the data to the proper coordinate system.

Please try the [*Project*](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Project/00170000007m000000/) tool, located in *Data Management Tools* → *Projections and Transformations* → *Feature*.

This should allow you to create a new feature class that is projected in the correct coordinate system.

If by chance your 3 shapefiles are of *unknown coordinate system*, please make sure to set the coordinate system (before proceeding with the above *Project* tool) for these shapefiles to that of their original projection by using the [*Define Projection*](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Define_Projection/001700000077000000/) tool, located in *Data Management Tools* → *Projections and Transformations*.

Answer (score 15):

This a simple tutorial one can follow to define (overwrite) or reproject (transform) a Coordinate Reference System (CRS) in ArcGIS 10.1+ starting from a **CSV file**. To clearly understand 'define' and 'reproject' concepts refer to [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/27059/16141).

1. Open ArcMap;
2. Click on `File --> Add Data --> Add XY Data`;
3. Browse the CSV file which contains column `A` with longitude (or Easting) values; and column `B` with latitude (or Northing) values. Example:

   ```
       easting     northing  
    732771.529  7457694.818  
    733006.267  7456350.588  
    735506.391  7481351.041
   ```

3.1. Select column A as the `X field` and column B as the `Y field` from the CSV file;

3.2. On `Coordinate System of Input Coordinates` field, select current CRS from data (or choose one manually).

Here the CRS is **defined**. One can export the layer to a shapefile by right clicking in the layer and then, `Data --> Export Data`.

---

Or continue (from item `3.2`) to **reproject**:

4. Click on `ArcToolBox` button (little red toolbox icon), then go through `DataManagementTools --> Projections and Transformations --> Feature --> Project`;

4.1. Select the input layer from the `Input Dataset or Feature Class` field;

4.2. In `Output Coordinate System` choose the CRS one wants data to be projected (transformed) to.

4.3. Set file path and name for the output file in `Output Dataset or Feature Class` field.

4.4. Click `Ok` and wait while `Project` finish running.

Here data is already **reprojected** to new CRS.

---

Now, let's create columns with new `X` and `Y` coordinates in the layer's table of attributes:

5. Right click the new created layer and select `Open Attribute Table`;

5.1. Click on `Table Options` (upper left corner), then `Add field` to add new `X` coordinates;

5.2. Chose a name for the column (e.g. `X_coords`) and set the `Type` field as `Double`.

5.3. Repeat steps (`5` to `5.2`) for creating column `Y_coords`;

6. Go back to the Attribute Table and right click `X_coords`;

6.1. Select `Calculate Geometry`. Set `Property` for `X_coords` equal `X coordinate of Point`. Verify if `Use coordinate system of the data source` is selected. Click `Ok`.

6.2. Repeat steps `6` and `6.1` for column `Y_coords`, but select `Y coordinate of Point` instead.