# Why did my shapefile distance get smaller after changing the projection?

Tags: arcmap, coordinate-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Layers having the same coordinate system should overlap, but they don't. What's wrong?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20572/layers-having-the-same-coordinate-system-should-overlap-but-they-dont-whats)

I'm working with a shapefile that has a geographic coordinate system and I need to change it to a projected coordinate system to use spatial analysis tools.

Steps:

1) I defined the coordinate system using the define projection tool to State Plane (US Feet) California Zone 6.

2) Then I used the Project tool to make define the coordinate system as the state plane system using a different name. I made sure not to use the same name and followed the guidelines listed here: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00130000004v000000.htm

When I measured the county with the measurement tool, it said it was less than a mile across (it measured about 34 miles across when the coordinate system was defined using the GCS). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!