# Convert decimal degrees to meters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, coordinate-system

I have a shapefile. The coordinates (Lat/Long) are projected as decimal degrees. But, I want to re-project it to meters.

How can I do it with ArcMap?

Comment: This is a FAQ; you can find many answers by searching on keywords like [project Arcmap shapefile](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=project+arcmap+shapefile). Perhaps the most complete answer appears at http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/27059.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [Project tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000007m000000) to project the data to a suitable projection, then if you want to see the coordinates in the table, add two fields (decimal) and use the Calculate Geometry option from the table to get the coordinates

Comment: (+1) Check first if your shapefile has a coordinate system defined. If no coordinate system is defined use [Define Projection](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Define_Projection/001700000077000000/) to assign the right system to your shapfile (I suspect WGS84 ?) before using Project tool.