# QGIS to solve projection mystery in Postgresql

Tags: qgis, postgis, coordinate-system, qgis-2

I downloaded some data from local agency.  Per QGIS 2.2, I defined the projection to 'EPSG:3587 - NAD83(NSRS2007) / Michigan Central' in postgresql (maybe ArcMap).  Data is in Postgresql 9.3.

I am putting this data on geoserver and probably thought to store it in the web mercator projection 3587.

You can see in the image the black square near Australia is where the features land but should be where the blue swingley circle is.  I brought in OpenStreetMap from OpenLayers plugin in QGIS and then brought in the borked layer.  The geometry scale doesn't seem to be off...or said differently...it's features seem to measure a reasonable distance.

If I had to guess I would say that I projected it correctly but may have defined it incorrectly in postgresql.  I could run through the steps again with new data (I did this a few months ago and subsequently got my laptop stolen so no trace of anything I did but my virtual servers humming along).

I would like to solve this problem as well as become well versed with QGIS.  Any ideas?

I was thinking of changing projection in Postgresql but I don't know what I'm doing.  Thanks!

[image]

Comment: This may be the old define vs project issue. What steps/tools did you do to change it? (Or did you - I'm unclear on if your local agency data *came* in 3587 or if you tried to *put* it in 3587 - I think you may have transposed a number in your question as OSM is 3857.) There is a tool that *sets* a projection and a tool that *changes* the projection - two very different things.  Also, have you enabled on-the-fly projection in your project?

Comment: In PostgreSQL, what does the SQL query "select * from public.geometry_columns" yield? And if you run the query "select ST_AsText(yourgeometrycolumn) from yourtable" do the actual co-ordinate numbers look right to you?

Comment: I agree with @ChrisW that you transposed 3857 as 3587 because you've circled Texas and the Gulf of Mexico, NOT Michigan. Please double-check with the data provider what the CRS is.

Comment: Sorry changed second sentence to 'Per QGIS 2.2, I defined the projection to 'EPSG:3587 - NAD83(NSRS2007) / Michigan Central' in postgresql (maybe ArcMap).  Data is in Postgresql 9.3.'

Comment: I will check to see if I possibly did the transformation from the local crs (State Plane of South Texas (Zone 4204) and Datum NAD 1983) to  3587 instead of 3857.

Comment: If you did this in Arc, you definitely used the wrong tool: [Define Projection](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20572/layers-with-same-coordinate-system-should-align-overlap-but-do-not/27059#27059) does not *change* the projection, it *sets* it. You need to Project from agency CRS to desired CRS. If this is supposed to be Texas and you've got something saying Michigan, then I'd say you have a compound problem - you didn't reproject, and when you redefined you transposed numbers. You'll need to go back to agency data, or take what you have, Define it back to agency, then project to OSM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I defined the srid wrong.  Transposed the 8 in 3857 for the 5.  I used the statement below to fix!!!!  Forest for the trees!

SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID('roads','geom',3857);