# My map is little bit off

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates, wgs84

I am pretty new in GIS things and i have been learning how to use QGIS. Most of the maps are fine, but yesterday I went to GIS center at my University and I got the maps of my country that I will be using for my study. But when I add them in QGIS they are not on the right spot. I checked the coordinate system and it is WGS 84. when I add the species, they are on the right place and map is little bit diagonally towards the right upper corner. I checked the species with the other map that I downloaded from internet and they are on the right place. Also the species and the other map that I downloaded from internet are WGS 84.

Any suggestions how can I correct this?

Comment: This [Q&A](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20572/layers-with-same-coordinate-system-should-align-overlap-but-do-not) may be worth you reviewing.  Do not be put off if it mentions ArcGIS rather than QGIS because the same principles apply.  Also, do not be afraid to edit your question to make your descriptions of the steps you have undertaken more precise.  Before any answers are offered is always the best time to do this.

Comment: How about a picture showing what you're explaining.

Comment: Better would be the extents of each layer. Almost certainly, some of the data is in a projected coordinate system and is incorrectly labeled as WGS84.