# Fix shapefile with basemap in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system

How I can fix the shapefile with the basemap in ArcGIS 10.2?

I have transform the basemap projection to GREECE GRID, the same with the shapefile...but they don't fix exactly...

I try to attach a Picture for the theme, but I cannot see it...

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user I recommend that you take the [Tour] and also review [How to frame a good question](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/how-to-frame-a-good-question).  I suspect your question may be a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20572/layers-with-same-coordinate-system-should-align-overlap-but-do-not so I also recommend reviewing that.

Comment: @thanassis - I concur with PolyGeo's suspicion that the thread he linked will hold the answer for you.