# Setting Method Parameters for ArcGIS Generating Near Table tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, proximity

I input firms' coordinates in the arcgis and want to calculate the distance of firms to the nearest polyline feature (roads). I am having a problem grasping the unit of near_dist value. All of them are in hundredth or thousandth like .00475. Most likely the value is expressed in the coordinate system. But I would like them to be shown as in the metric system.

ArcGis has a help file that mentions you need to change the method parameter from planar to geodesic and that conversion will give you an near_dist value in meters.

But I am really **having trouble to find the method parameter setting.** Can anyone walk me through how to find it. I am using **ArcMap 10.2** and **windows 32-bit**.

[image]

output:
[image]

Comment: Confirm that your layer is in WGS84, if it is, then project the data into a coordinate system where the units of measure are in metres.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Ok, I changed both the point layer and the line layer to WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_20N and the linear units are meters. But my near_dist value is still so small. Do I not do something to get it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that both of your datasets are in the same coordinate system, and make sure that it is a coordinate system whose linear unit is Metres.  The output measurement should then be in metres.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I put both my datasets in WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_20N and the unit of measure is meters. But I still can't get a sensible near_dist value. Could you tell me where I did wrong ?

Comment: Looking at the image the nearest XY coordinate would suggest the data is still in decimal degrees. You did project the data using the _project tool_ rather than use the _define projection_ tool?

Comment: @Hornbydd Thanks for spotting my misstep. Instead of using the define projection tool, I use the project tool this time to project both layers into WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_12N. I am putting the results as images above. I don't think the result is satisfactory. NearXY coordinate is messed up. Near_dist value is changed but is still too small.

Comment: A post said "WGS84 and NAD83 both refer to datums not projections. If you want to project your data, I would be inclined to use either a UTM zone, or a US-wide projection if you're dealing with large areas."  I tried changing the prj coordinate system  to USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic_USGS_version. It's still not working.

Comment: Ok. I just figured it out. Please refer to this post and see mkennedy and Chris W's comments. They are very helpful.  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154652/arcmap-point-distance-giving-decimal-degrees-even-when-in-projected-coordinate-s