# How to transform any GeoTIFF to Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area with GDAL?

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I am trying to transform a GeoTIFF EPSG:4326 `+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs`
and a GeoTIFF EPSG:31982 `+proj=utm +zone=22 +south +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs` both to EPSG:102020 `+proj=laea +lat_0=-90 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs`

Command used:

```
gdal_translate -a_srs "+proj=laea +lat_0=-90 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" -of GTiff "source path" "target path"
```

Results:

The target file for EPSG:4326 seems to be in the right place, but in wrong scale (pixel size unchanged). The target file for EPSG:31982 seems to be in the right scale, but in wrong place.

I already tried the following commands:

```
gdalwarp -overwrite -s_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs" -t_srs "+proj=laea +lat_0=-90 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" -r near -multi -of GTiff "source path" "target path"
```

and

```
gdalwarp -overwrite -s_srs "+proj=utm +zone=22 +south +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs" -t_srs "+proj=laea +lat_0=-90 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" -r near -multi -of GTiff "source path" "target path"
```

Both results seems to be in wrong place and wrong angle (rotated).

How to solve this geotransformation with GDAL?

Comment: How do you determine that they are rotated/wrongly transformed and it isn't an issue with the display options of your GIS?

Comment: Gdal_translate is wrong tool for you, -a_srs does not do anything else than write given parameters to the target file. If it was EPSG:4326 in the beginning after applying the LAEA paremeters with -a_srs it is still an EPSG:4326 image but with wrong metadata. Cases when -a_srs can be used are a) source image is missing srs metadata but you know what it should be and b) source image is having wrong srs metadata but you know what it should be.

Comment: So, my need isn`t a translation but a reprojection! My problem is solved. I checked the metadata and it is not "+lat_0=-90 +lon_0=0" but "+lat_0=-15 +lon_0=-60". Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @user30184 in comments, [gdal_translate](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) won't reproject the raster. The `a_srs` parameter is useful to write correct coordinate reference system to files when they are not defined or are incorrectly defined within metadata:

> -a_srs srs_def:
>   Override the projection for the output file. The srs_def may be any of the usual GDAL/OGR forms, complete WKT, PROJ.4, EPSG:n or a file containing the WKT. **No reprojection is done.**

On the other hand, [gdalwarp](https://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) does reprojection but you were setting the source spatial reference set (i.e., the `-s_srs` parameter) with incorrect values as acknowledged in [this comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/61664/jo%c3%a3o-lucas-lara-rodrigues).

---

Defining a CRS (SRS) *versus* reprojecting it is a classical FAQ in GIS. For example, in GIS SE: [Layers with same coordinate system should align/overlap in ArcMap but do not?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20572/layers-with-same-coordinate-system-should-align-overlap-in-arcmap-but-do-not/27059#27059)