# Is it possible to visualize EPSG:102020 and EPSG:3857 at same time in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, epsg

Is it possible to visualize EPSG:102020 and EPSG:3857 at same time in QGIS?
If is possible, how?

Why some EPSG permit on the fly transformation and visualization and other don`t?

Answer (score 6):

There are two issues with what you are trying to do here, first [EPSG:102020](http://epsg.io/102020) is not really an EPSG code it is an ESRI code so there is always a risk that non ESRI software will be unable to handle it.

The second and more fundamental one is that ESRI:102020 is a (south) polar projection while [EPSG:3857](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/6864/) is a Transverse Mercator projection which goes to infinity at the poles so it is not able to show the polar regions which is what is being shown in your other data set.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The answer make total sense... if I can`t visualize all together in this case, I need to reproject/translate the data. I asked a related question in this link http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168691/how-to-transform-any-gtiff-to-lambert-azimuthal-equal-area-with-gdal If anyone can help me would be grateful.