# Same coordinate system - shapefiles don't overlap

Tags: coordinate-system, overlay, overlapping-features

I have two shapefiles and two rasters (dem), and while I put them in the same coordinate system (Greek grid), it seems that they don't overlap.  But one is the boundaries of a county, and another the polygon layer with the drought statistics of the same area.. So they should overlap but don't.

Comment: "Same coordinate system" is the boner here. I don't think it's true.

Comment: "while I put them in the same coordinate system" . You cannot do "put" data from differing datasets into the same coordinate system. You need to reproject (not project) them. Most likely this, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20572/layers-with-same-coordinate-system-should-align-overlap-but-do-not?rq=1

Comment: At first i didn't understand what you wrote.. But now i see.. You mean that in this case, we're having two shp files and two rasters. You're saying that we can't have the same coordinate system in different datasets. But what can i do? i mean, the rasters and everything are about the same thing. So they need to be overlapped.. Can you help me if i send you the data?

Comment: This is not what I mean but this is your final exam so you should work it out.

Answer (score 1):

Using QGIS, You have to use `Save as ...` for vector data and `Raster -> Projections -> Warp (Reproject)` for raster data to **reproject** the data to the same CRS, under a new filename for each dataset. Arcgis and other GIS software might be similar.

`Set Layer CRS` is not the same, and will corrupt your data. You better start with a fresh copy of the original data.