# projection (WGS84, UTM) issue

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, wgs84, utm

I have a question about projections. I have a hillshade raster with UTM 31N projection (I reprojected this from WGS 84). I also have a satellite image that I need to georeference. For georeferencing I choose UTM 31N as projection for the modified satellite image, however when it opens in QGIS, it is not in the same spot as the hillshade raster. When I change the projection of the modified satellite image to WGS 84, it works well and they overlap. What did I do wrong?

UL: 41˚46'40'' / 0˚30'19''
LR: 42˚37'28'' / 1˚01'37''

Comment: Please edit the question to include the extents of the projected and unprojected rasters.

Comment: We need the extent of **both** rasters to be able to provide any assistance. Please be sure to mark ordinates with direction  (N/S/E/W/X/Y)

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20572/layers-with-same-coordinate-system-should-align-overlap-but-do-not

Answer (score 1):

You thought to reproject to UTM by using `Set Layer CRS`, which is wrong. You have altered the CRS, but not the extent.

You need `Raster -> Projections -> Warp` to reproject raster data correctly to another filename and CRS.