# Layer projection too big in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: coordinate-system, layers, arcgis-pro

How do I resize & replace a layer that is displaced & too big?

[image]

The purple background above is actually a layer representing a state. I have tried using "Define Projection" and "Project" tool, but I wasn't successful with it.

I am really new to this software.

Comment: See this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20572/layers-with-same-coordinate-system-should-align-overlap-but-do-not. Most likely, you should not have used the Define Projection tool at all.