# Why is my CRS not projecting data points where they are meant to be using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am trying to plot pipelines which are expressed as multiple data points. For each data point there is a *Northing* and *Easting* which have been projected using the ED50 30N projection.

[image]

I need my data to be in WGS84 EPSG:4326. I have loaded a new QGIS with the basemap projection of WGS84. I have then uploaded the data as a `delimited text file`. When uploaded, I thought the points were not appearing. However, from closer invesigation they are just being projected far, far off the base map as seen below (bear in mind 'Peterhead' is actually situated within the world map, as seen in the 3rd figure ).

[image]

The figure above identifies two seperate pipelines which have been input. However the scale below is 0:1 (Which is as large as QGIS can go).

[image]

This figure can show how large the map is, as peterhead is situated within the world map.

Can anyone solve this issue. I have taken the first Easting and Northing idicated within the first figure and tested it within the map. It projects the data to the west coast of scotland seen in the bottom figure (nevertheless this is still wrong as it should be on the east coast of scotland). However, even if my coodinates are wrong my projections shouldnt be as far away as they are. does anyone know why?

I have tried *exporting feature* and saving it as a new shapefile with the WGS 84 projection, but it still occurs in the same place.

However, even if my coodinates are wrong my projections shouldnt be as far away as they are. does anyone know why?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Layers with same coordinate system should align/overlap in ArcMap but do not?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20572/layers-with-same-coordinate-system-should-align-overlap-in-arcmap-but-do-not)

Comment: I am using QGIS not ARCGIS, therfore the function are not the same to amend the error

Comment: Can you provide your data points as *text* and not an *image of text* because it saves us typing them all out again.

Comment: I get the same location for the first two points as you. I am using EPSG:23030 for your coordinates. That is where they are. If the points aren't in the right place then either the projection is the wrong projection or the numbers are wrong or your belief in where the points should be is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

When you import your data be sure to set the projection to ED50 30N otherwise QGis will treat them as being in lat/lon degrees and plot them a long way away from where they should be.

Comment: I have done this and when I add _delimited text layer_ in ED50 CRS the layer is essentially 'invisiable' and doesnt show up on my map.

Comment: I have tried to fix this by exporting the layer and saving the vector layer as an 'ESRI Shapefile' with the CRS now changed to WGS84 epsg:4326, and this doesnt seem to work either.

Comment: @Bodhi It shouldn't be any different, but did you try the "Define Projection" tool after adding your data? After you load your data points into QGIS, use the "Define Projection" tool to make sure they're in a ED50 50N CRS. This should situate them to the correct location on your basemap. Then you can use the "Reproject" tool or export them the way you were doing.

Comment: I have just used the "Define Projection" tool and pressed Run and it has situated the data in the same place. I have used the Reproject tool, and once again it is in the same place. which to me as @spacedman suggested, the data points must be in a different place to where I thought they were. However, It doesnt explain how (after extracting the Northing's and Eastings Manually and individually) and using the 'long/lat plugin' how they indicate that the data points are actually on the west of scotland not where the figures above are indicating

Answer (score 1):

By using this setting on your first three point (due to my localisation the CSV separator is a semicolon and the decimal separator is comma, this could be different for you so adjust if needed)

[image]

I got the 3 points to appear in northern Scotland west coast (see below image)

[image]

So it seem that your coordinate map here, if you are sure that they should be on the east coast either the projection is false (ie. not ED50 30N) or the coordinate are false.

Comment: That's exactly where the questioner gets their first point. They have said it shouldn't be there, it should be on the other side of Scotland.

Comment: So the projection is false (ie. not ED50 30N) or the coordinate are false

Comment: @J.R I have tried different projections and have found out that ED50N EPGS: 4320 31N situates my data points in the correct place. I have contacted the source company of data and got them to change it to the correct projection.

Comment: Just for fun try epsg 27700