# Zonal Statistics as Table: 999999 Error

Tags: arcmap, zonal-statistics, raster-conversion, error-999999, ascii

I am receiving a 999999 error each time that I attempt to run Zonal Statistics as Table. I am attempting to overlay population data from an asc file with a shp file with French Alsatian municipal boundaries delineated as features. I am working on arcmap 10.6

I converted the asc file to a raster (with the "ASCII to Raster" tool) and then used it as the input value raster in the Zonal Statistics as Table tool. I use a shp file for the feature zone data. I have found that I get an error if leave the processing extent set to Default, but this goes away if I set it at the extent of the (asc) input value raster.

I think that the issue may be stemming from the asc file used for the input value raster. Its properties indicate that it has an "Undefined" spatial reference, and the shp file used to input feature zone data has not produced this 999999 issue when used with other non asc files.

I also get the following message box when I first create a layer from the asc file in question:

> The following data sources you added are missing spatial reference
>   information. This data can be drawn in ArcMap, but cannot be
>   projected.

I have followed the directions from https://community.esri.com/thread/47038; Neither selecting a coordinate system from the properties window nor using the "define projection" tool has resolved this issue.

[image]

One other potential lead is that the issue stems from the relative size of the shp projection vs that of the asc; When I zoom to the layer of the asc file, I have to scroll out from 1;1081 to about 1:50,000,000 before the shp file in question even appears in view. By that point the world map from the asc file is too small to be visible.

[edit]: Here are a few pictures to depict what I said about the raster and shapefile not overlapping. [image: Zoomed to Raster Layer] [image: Zoomed out] [image: Zoomed out until shapefile is visible]

Comment: Please explain "I have to scroll out from 1;1081 to about 1:50,000,000 before the shp file in question even appears in view".  So the raster and shapefile do not overlap?  Or they overlap but the raster is projecting smaller than it should? It certainly seems like you need to apply the correct projection/coordinate system to your raster.

Comment: The raster and shapefile do not overlap. I used the "define projection" tool to defne the appropriate xy coordinate system for the raster file. They use the same coordinate system, but I continue to get the same 99999 error. I will include a picture in my main question depicting the relative locations of the roster file (world map) and shapefile (French municipalities) when projected.

Comment: The are not in the same projection or GCS, or else they would align.  You can define them as the same coordinate system but that will not mathematically transform them into the same coordinate system.  You need to find out what projection, if any, your ascii file is natively.  The other option is to georeference your raster to your shapefile, or some other reference layer, as long as accuracy is not paramount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any of the geoprocessing tools in ArcToolbox that involve raster + vector interactions/operations require the data  share the same coordinate reference system.

Because your raster's CRS is not defined, ArcMap does not know what the pixel size of the raster should be.   It this case ArcMap assumes that the CRS of the raster is the same as the dataframe and so the pixel size is the unit of measure of your dataframe's CRS

Figure out the CRS of the raster file.  Use Define Projection to assign the CRS to the raster.  Reproject one of the datasets if they are not the same so that they are the same, and try again.

Comment: I have used the define projection tool to assign the raster to the same coordinate system as the shp file, but the same issue still appears.

Comment: The definition of the projection of the raster file must match the actual projection of the raster data.

Comment: This may be exactly the issue. The following link (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20572/layers-with-same-coordinate-system-should-align-overlap-in-arcmap-but-do-not) suggests begining by defining the projection according to the data AND THEN using the "project" tool to change the CRS if needed to match my shape file. I am less clear on how to identify the CRS which corresponds with the underlying data of my acs file. Hopefully the first few lines of text data contain helpful identifying info: ncols 4320
nrows 2160
xllcorner -180
yllcorner -90
cellsize 0.0833333
nodata_value -9999

Comment: It does sound like it is using geographic coordinates (grid cell location corresponds to degrees)  Try defining the raster as WGS84 and see if that gets you in the ballpark.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be that there is no surface from the vector layer in the raster overlay, in which case it is a formal error of the Zonal Statistics as Table tool.

If working with an arcpy script, "try - except" is used so that the calculation is not interrupted.

Otherwise, errors in the geometry of the vector layer should be looked at and possibly corrected with the Repair Geometry tool.