# Converting LAS Dataset into a point feature class with x-y-z in the attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, lidar, arcgis-10.5, las

How can I convert a LAS data set (displayed as LAS point elevation in ArcGIS 10.5) into a point feature class with x-y-z information attached to it (or stored in the  attribute table)?

ArcGIS has the `LAS to Multipoint` tool (and then the `Multipart to Singlepart` tool), but the created output doesn't include any coordinates nor height information, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After converting the LAS Dataset to a point feature class, then add x, y and z coordinates to the attribute table with [Add Geometry Attributes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-geometry-attributes.htm) tool:

> Adds new attribute fields to the input features representing the spatial or geometric characteristics and location of each feature, such as length or area and x-, y-, z-, and m- coordinates.

Another option is to use the `Calculate Geometry` tool. See steps 5 and 6 from [Layers with same coordinate system should align/overlap in ArcMap but do not?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20572/layers-with-same-coordinate-system-should-align-overlap-in-arcmap-but-do-not/54601#54601).

---

I am not sure why you want to do this, but be cautious converting optimized point cloud LAS/LAZ format to a point feature class format. It might be cumbersome depending on the point cloud size.