# Buffer (for 8 points) is set at 1 kilometer but is bigger than village polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, buffer

[image]

Other details

- This is in the Philippines and I'm using WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_51N
- The buffer is 1km long so it must be the map layer that is wrong
- I tried the Geodesic method instead of Planar but still got the same problem
- Posted on [r/gis](https://www.reddit.com/r/gis/comments/e3eyu6/buffer_for_points_is_set_at_1_kilometer_but_is/) and [r/arcgis](https://www.reddit.com/r/ArcGIS/comments/e3ez2k/buffer_for_points_is_set_at_1_kilometer_but_is/) and am still lost on what I'm doing wrong so I posted here

Is the extent perhaps wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is a problem with the spatial reference of your layer. The extent seems to correspond to geographic coordinates in degrees, but the crs assigned to the layer is a projected one - UTM Zone 51 in meters.

You could try the following and see if it resolves the issue:

- Set your layer crs to GCS_WGS_1984 (epsg 4326) with Define Projection tool
- Project your layer to WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_51N with the Project tool.
- Check if the layer aligns with data from other sources or a basemap. If it does, then buffer your layer.

I would check the other layers as well, from what I see, they may have the same problem as your point layer.

This sort of issue can happen when we [confuse the Define Projection and Project functions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/27059/82947), and when a layer crs is changed directly in the feature class properties instead of using the Project tool.

Comment: Thank you. I'll do those when I encounter the same problem again. For now, I just redownloaded and redid all my data. :)