# ERROR 999999 from Project Raster - any advice?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system, arcmap, error-999999

I have a DEM layer (TIFF raster) for the island of Crete downloaded from the EU Copernicus EU-DEM website and a point data layer for locations of interest around the island.

I cannot seem to get the two layers to match up, whereby the point data lay on top of the DEM. Been searching through previous questions on here and seemingly nothing I have done is able to sort the issue.

```
Current data frame Coordinate System: *GCS_WGS_1984*  
TIF Raster XY Coordinate System: *GCS_WGS_1984*  
Point data Coordinate System: *GCS_WGS_1984*  
Point data Projected Coordinate System: *WGS_1984_UTM_ZONE_34N*
```

I have tried to project the raster into *WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_34N* with the hope that they will match up. However, the **Project Raster** tool is not working and I keep getting the following error (see image). I have been trying for two days!

[image: error]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Layers not lining up is an FAQ (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20572) but I think you should focus this question on why you are getting an ERROR 999999 from Project Raster.

Comment: The coordinates shown in the lower right corner in your screenshot say "5923572.474  1193191.801 Decimal Degrees" which means something is wrong with the crs of your raster.

Comment: These coordinates look like epsg 3035 coordinates for that area, as stated on the dem download website. My guess is that you assigned WGS84 instead of projecting. Make sure your raster layer is set to epsg 3035 (ETRS89 / LAEA Europe) before proceeding to Project Raster. Do not simply assign a coordinate system, as this does not perform any transformation, it simply overwrites the coordinate system, thereby corrupting your spatial reference.

Comment: The bad CRS is why Project Raster is returning empty geometry. The raster extents don't make sense for lat/lon so when it tries to reproject them, the values end up nonsensical/NaN.