# Layers with same spatial reference do not overlay?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, arcgis-pro

I have two shapefiles (Parks and VMCC), and both the shapefiles have the same spatial reference (NAD 1983 HARN Adj MN Dakota (US Feet)).

[image]
[image]

The Parks.shp falls at the exact location where it should, the issue occurs with VMCC and it is falling at an inaccurate location.

[image]
[image]

Extent information **VMCC**
[image]

What all I have tried:-

- Used the project tool to set the spatial reference for both the layers to Web Mercator
- Deleted the .prj file and used the define projection tool to give the required projection

The behavior is reproducible in ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro.

What is a possible reason for this?

Comment: The VMCC layer seems to be a building interior plan. Did it originally come from a CAD or BIM file? What is the extent of that original layer (before any operation was performed on it)? I.e. what do the coordinates look like? It is possible that building interior plans aren't georeferenced properly, but also make sure you do not confuse the  [Define projection and the Project operations](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/27059/82947)

Comment: We need the VMCC extent. Can you please edit your question with that information. VMCC almost certainly has the wrong coordinate reference system. We have to figure out what it could be--regular state plane zone, Dakota system in meters...

Comment: @mkennedy, thank you :), I have added the extent info, also I was referring to "FsimardGIS" explanation and found that this could be in the local coordinate system https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000007880, and we might need to create a custom projection file https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012038.

Comment: @YogeshChavan Thank you! I think you're right that it's in a local CRS. Something that may help--does it look like the data size/extent is correct? That is, the layer should be about 7-8000 feet across, etc?