# How to put TIFF orthomosaic in GCS projection show up over LAS dataset and rasters

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap

I'm working in ArcMap. I have an orthomosaic (TIFF) that was originally projected in WGS 1984 and EGM2008 vertical datum. I need it to match up with a LAS dataset and the associated rasters, which are in a state plane projection (NAD 1983 HARN State Plane Hawaii 4 FIPS 5104 Feet) and vertical datum of NAVD88 in feet. I ran the define projection tool for the TIFF to put it into the above projection, but it still doesn't display over the LAS dataset. It also won't display over the imagery basemap, while the LAS Dataset does. What am I missing here?

Comment: What software are you using? Any kind of guidance depends on what software you have available.

Comment: I'm using ArcMap.

Comment: I see you've made a common mistake: Define projection assigns a projection to a dataset, it **does not project the data**, you need to set it back to what it was before and then run project raster https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000007q000000 to transform it into the correct location. You will need to specify a datum transformation to go from WGS84 to NAD83, there is a list https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/how-to-determine-which-nad1983towgs1984-transformation-000005929

Comment: This is the most common question in GIS SE, allowing that there are several different flavors (one for each software platform). This is the canonical "Use 'Project' not 'Define'" for ArcGIS: [Layers with same coordinate system should align/overlap in ArcMap but do not?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20572/layers-with-same-coordinate-system-should-align-overlap-in-arcmap-but-do-not)